# Android- Change colour and have ripples on layout at the same time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-selector, rippledrawable

I have a `LinearLayout`. I have applied ripple effect on it which is working fine.  What I'm doing is when user clicks on it, it should change its colour to White (default is Gray). If clicked again, it should become Gray again. This I achieved using `layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);`.

But I want both ripples and this colour toggle. If I use `setBackgroundColor`, the ripple effect vanishes. Any clue about how to do this?

XML for ripples (background of `LinearLayout`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/divider">
<item android:drawable="@color/background" />
</ripple>
```

Please suggest equivalent solution for pre-lollipop devices. The background for this `LinearLayout` on pre-lollipop is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/divider" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setBackgroundColor, use `setImageDrawable()` and pass the id of your xml layout (R.drawable.your_layout).

Define two different xml layouts: one with a grey back and the other with a white background.

**White background**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/divider">
    <item android:drawable="#ffffff" />
    </ripple>
```

**Grey Background**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/divider">
    <item android:drawable="888888" />
    </ripple>
```

Comment: Okay, but how to make it White?